# Iterate JSON array and find all matched values

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex, factory-bot

So I am trying to find all elements within the json array below with an email with the domain example.com

JSON Array used:

```
[{"addedAt"=>123456,
  "vid"=>123456,
  "canonical-vid"=>123456,
  "merged-vids"=>[],
  "portal-id"=>123456,
  "is-contact"=>true,
  "profile-token"=>"portal-token-goes-here",
  "profile-url"=>"portal-url-goes-here",
  "properties"=>{"firstname"=>{"value"=>"Ramon"}, "lastmodifieddate"=>{"value"=>"12345"}, "company"=>{"value"=>"Some Company"}, "lastname"=>{"value"=>"Carleones"}},
  "form-submissions"=>
   [{"conversion-id"=>"some-convo-id-goes-here",
     "timestamp"=>123456,
     "form-id"=>"form-id-goes-here",
     "portal-id"=>405406,
     "page-url"=>"page-url-goes-here",
     "content-type"=>"standard-page",
     "page-title"=>"page-title-goes-here",
     "title"=>"title-goes-here",
     "first-visit-url"=>"first-visit-url-goes-here",
     "first-visit-timestamp"=>123456,
     "meta-data"=>[]}],
  "identity-profiles"=>
   [{"vid"=>123456,
     "saved-at-timestamp"=>123456,
     "deleted-changed-timestamp"=>0,
     "identities"=>[{"type"=>"EMAIL", "value"=>"ramon@example.com", "timestamp"=>123456}, {"type"=>"Important", "value"=>"some-value", "timestamp"=>123456}]}],
  "merge-audits"=>[]},
 {"addedAt"=>123456,
  "vid"=>123456,
  "canonical-vid"=>123456,
  "merged-vids"=>[],
  "portal-id"=>123456,
  "is-contact"=>true,
  "profile-token"=>"portal-token-goes-here",
  "profile-url"=>"profile-url-goes-here",
  "properties"=>{"firstname"=>{"value"=>"Sally"}, "lastmodifieddate"=>{"value"=>"123456"}, "company"=>{"value"=>"Acme Inc."}, "lastname"=>{"value"=>"Jackson"}},
  "form-submissions"=>
   [{"conversion-id"=>"some-convo-id-goes-here",
     "timestamp"=>123456,
     "form-id"=>"some-form-id",
     "portal-id"=>123456,
     "title"=>"Big Freakin Title",
     "meta-data"=>[]}],
  "identity-profiles"=>
   [{"vid"=>123456,
     "saved-at-timestamp"=>123456,
     "deleted-changed-timestamp"=>0,
     "identities"=>[{"type"=>"EMAIL", "value"=>"sjackson@acme-example.com", "timestamp"=>123456}, {"type"=>"Team Lead", "value"=>"some-value", "timestamp"=>123456}]}],
  "merge-audits"=>[]
  }]
```

Here is the code I was trying:
I used factory girl and used an instance variable:

```
#@json_array.contacts_obtained is a hash - contacts_obtained is the key, and the 
#value is the actual json array above.

      @json_array.contacts_obtained.detect do |i| i['identity-profiles'][0]['identities'][0]['value'] == /@example.com/
puts i
end
```

I wasn't sure if it was ok to do a regex there like that. It doesn't appear to work when I tried that. So I was wondering if there was another way to do this.

I am trying to obtain all the elements with @example.com domain so I can 'pop' them or remove them from the json array. Essentially I need a filter. That will filter out all the array elements with certain domain emails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Use [`=~`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E) instead of `==` iy ou want to match a string with a regexp:

```
@json_array.contacts_obtained.select do |i| 
  i['identity-profiles'][0]['identities'][0]['value'] =~ /@example.com/
end
```

Comment: thanks, also another quick question. will the detect method go through the entire array to find all possibilities that match that regex? I'm worried it will stop after the first possible match in the array.

Comment: `detect` will just return the first match. Use `select` if you want to return all matches.

Comment: cool thanks, is there a method to automatically remove from array once it finds it?

Comment: Sure, there is the [`delete_if`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) method. I recommend to have a look at the documentation of the most used core classes like: String, Hash, Array...

Comment: so i tried this: '@json_array.contacts_obtained.delete_at' i right below the 'select' statement and it returned:  'TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into Integer' I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I wrote `delete_if`, not `delete_at`. `delete_if` takes a block like `detect` and `select`, `delete_at` takes an integer (the index of the element to delete).

Comment: thanks, thats what I needed. this appeared to have worked. based on the docs it looks like delete_if will search through the entire array like the select method. correct me here if I am wrong. Thanks